# IOS:Creating a Self-Sizing UITextView Within a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am using stroyboards for my project. My project is based on parsing json datas and displaying it in JSON. While parsing JSON I will receive two different datas. `Title and Description`
i have to parse this and have to fix in `UItextview inside a uitableviewcell` i have structured a uitableviewcell like this

[image]

TEXTVIEW,TEXTVIEW,LABEL,LABEL,LABEL,LABEL,LABEL;
Now my problem is my text view has to resize according to data, and based on that tableviewcell also has to resize I tried the above code but the view gets collapsing.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Need_Request";
    NeedReqListCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    type = (NSString *)[array4 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if([type isEqualToString:@"Money Donation"]) {
        cell.createdby.text = (NSString *)[array3 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.product.text = (NSString *)[array4 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.expiration.text = (NSString *)[array5 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.titleview.text = (NSString *)[array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell.descview setHidden:TRUE];
        [cell.totalquantity setHidden:TRUE];
        [cell.fulfilledquantity setHidden:TRUE];
        return cell;

    }
    else if([type isEqualToString:@"Service"]) {
        cell.createdby.text = (NSString *)[array3 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.product.text = (NSString *)[array4 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.expiration.text = (NSString *)[array5 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.titleview.text = (NSString *)[array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.descview.text = (NSString *)[array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell.totalquantity setHidden:TRUE];
        [cell.fulfilledquantity setHidden:TRUE];
        return cell;

    }

    cell.createdby.text = (NSString *)[array3 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.product.text = (NSString *)[array4 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.expiration.text = (NSString *)[array5 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.totalquantity.text = (NSString *)[array6 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.fulfilledquantity.text = (NSString *)[array7 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.titleview.text = (NSString *)[array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.descview.text = (NSString *)[array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    CGRect bodyFrame = cell.titleview.frame;
    bodyFrame.size = cell.titleview.contentSize;
    [cell.titleview setFrame:bodyFrame];
    CGRect bodyFrame1 = cell.descview.frame;
    bodyFrame1.size = cell.descview.contentSize;
    [cell.descview setFrame:bodyFrame1];
    CGRect bodyFrame2 = cell.createdby.frame;
    [cell.createdby setFrame:bodyFrame2];
    CGRect bodyFrame3 = cell.product.frame;
    [cell.product setFrame:bodyFrame3];
    CGRect bodyFrame4 = cell.expiration.frame;
    [cell.expiration setFrame:bodyFrame4];
    CGRect bodyFrame5 = cell.totalquantity.frame;
    [cell.totalquantity setFrame:bodyFrame5];
    CGRect bodyFrame6 = cell.fulfilledquantity.frame;    
     [cell.fulfilledquantity setFrame:bodyFrame6];


    return cell;

}
```

when i tried this code my screen looks like this

[image]

Please help me to Solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Check this link - http://www.springtiger.co.uk/2010/11/28/dynamically-generate-labels-frame-to-match-its-content/

It will explain how to resize UIlabel to fit contents.

One more suggestion would be use a single control and use NSFormatted Text instead of so many labels. (Again it depends on your requirement).

Comment: But I need to set it in uitextview.

Comment: also i need to set it inside uitableviewcell

Comment: Is your textview editable ? If Not you can use a single control. And Use NSAttributedString to format the text.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the labels' frame origin as well so that they are placed below each other. So after you calculate the first textView's size and bounds, set the origin of the second textView to whichever offset from the bottom of the first textView. But that gets complicated when you have to take into account different orientations and device screen sizes...

Why don't you use auto-layout and constraints?

Comment: i have no idea reg autolayout and constraints. can you please help me with possible solution.

Comment: Watch this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/64392/video-tutorial-beginning-auto-layout.